# About calculations among a few tables joined with UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I have difficult query and now I need to devide the result of this query on data from another table. Used UNION. Is it right? Why I doesn't work?

```
SELECT * from (select IFnull(t.diapason,'total') as diapason, count(distinct 
user_id) / total_visitors*100 AS 'percent_of_users'
FROM 
(SELECT p.user_id, p.amount as total, CASE  
when amount<10 then '0-10' 
when amount>=10 then '10 +' END AS diapason
FROM 
    (SELECT payments.user_id, SUM(amount) AS amount 
    FROM payments INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, login_time FROM activity where login_time 
between '2018-04-12' and '2018-04-18') a 
ON payments.user_id = a.user_id and a.login_time = payments.payment_time 
GROUP BY payments.user_id) p
) t
  GROUP BY diapason WITH ROLLUP) as t1

UNION
SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id) as total_visitors FROM activity where 
login_time between '2018-04-12' and '2018-04-18'
ORDER BY percent_of_users desc;
```

I did UNION because I need to get total_visitors.

Thanks!

The result

```
diapason    percent_of_visitors
0-10          ...%
10+           ...%
```

To calculate percent_of_visitors (new value of activity.user_id / old value of activity.user_id).

But I don't know how to get access to old value. Can U give me hints?

Comment: The error message (that you should actually include) already tells you what is wrong here: in a `union`, all parts need to have the same amount of columns. As to how to fix it: it is unclear what you are trying to do ("and now I need to devide the result of this query on data from another table"), so can you elaborate on this, preferably with sample data, e.g. some rows for both parts each (before doing the `union`), and the expected result based on those (to understand what "devide" should do, as you seem to not be sure if that is done with a `union` at all).

Comment: @Solarflare Your comment contains the answer. Why not write an answer?

Comment: @O.Jones The actual question seems to be "Is that right?", and I am not really sure what he is trying to achieve (although I am pretty sure that a `union` is not correct, it looks more like he needs a `join` or a subquery).

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, Hello! I updated desired result

Comment: @Solarflare, I updated, look plz

Comment: Your question is framed as if your query works without the `union` (e.g. if you replace `total_visitors` in your second line with `100` and remove the part beginning with `union`), and you need a way to have the actual value of total visitors (a single constant value for that query) there. Can you verify that?

Comment: @Solarflare, yes , right

Comment: @Solarflare, Maybe , its better to use 'inner join activity on activity.login_time = t.payment_time'?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you want to change, but it looks like it would change the result of the inner query (`p`), as your join might not be on distinct login times anymore (so you may get more rows), but again, I am not sure what exactly you want to change there). I wrote you an answer, but I am assumig your query (apart from the union) is working and giving you the correct result (apart from having the percentage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your working query

```
SELECT ifnull(t.diapason,'total') as diapason,
   COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS user_count
FROM ...
```

you can include the `total_visitors` with a subquery:

```
SELECT ifnull(t.diapason,'total') as diapason,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) * 100 /
     (SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id) 
      FROM activity WHERE ...) as percent_of_users
FROM (...) t
GROUP BY diapason WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY percent_of_users DESC
```

Alternatively, you can use a `join` (which is closer to the query structure you intended):

```
SELECT t1.diapason, 
  t1.user_count * 100 / tv.total_users as percent_of_users
FROM ( SELECT ifnull(t.diapason,'total') as diapason,
         COUNT(distinct user_id) AS user_count
       FROM ...
     ) as t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(distinct user_id) as total_visitors 
      FROM activity WHERE ...) as tv
ORDER BY percent_of_users DESC
```

I used your aliases `t1` and `t` to mark which part of your query belongs where.

In both cases, the total count will only be calculated once, still, MySQL will execute the two queries slightly differently (it should not have a big effect though). You may want to include a check for a count of `0` (and thus division by `0`), although that should not happen here.

A remark: For MySQL 8+, you can simplify (and clarify) your code a bit if you use a [cte](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), since you currently basically repeat the code of subquery `a` twice (once in your actual query, once in the calculation of the total count), which can get annoying and confusion if it is more complicated than a simple `where`.

Comment: thank U for help! It has given me the right idea)
I 've changed my code. Only one trouble: It devides on groups wrong. The total percent is right.

According to my task , group must be devided if user_id is in the table payments due to his payment he ever did. 
But when I make the query it I thint begins to devide on groups due to his payment in period . I updated code below in question.Please watch

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков This is (if I understand correctly that `total_visitors` works) a new question and you should ask a new one (you can leave me the link to it here if you want), it's only marginally related to your original question and specifically the answer. So ask a new one, it's no problem and actually encouraged to keep the questions "clean". Include some sample data (input, result you get, result you want), and try to reduce it to the required minimum (`t1`?), e.g. you can leave out the parts related to `total_visitors`, as you (hopefully) know now how to include it into your altered code.

Comment: please watch the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218932/how-to-select-sums-of-certain-id-and-devide-the-result-by-groups

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do something with this kind of pattern.

```
 SELECT a, b, c FROM tbl 
 UNION
 SELECT d FROM tbl
```

You Can't Do That™. The two result sets in a union must have the same number of columns, and each column must be the same datatype in each of the result sets.

Comment: may be there's another way to do this? (I updated task)