# How to select sums of certain 'id' and devide the result by groups

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

In this query I try to select the sums of payments the users had made:

```
SELECT *
from (select IFnull(t.diapason,'total') as diapason,
t.total_amount as total_amount 

FROM 
(SELECT p.user_id, p.amount as total_amount, CASE
when amount<=100 then '0-100'
when amount>100 then '100...' END AS diapason
FROM (SELECT distinct payments.user_id, SUM(amount) AS amount 
FROM payments inner JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM payments where 
     payment_time between '2000-01-01' and '2001-01-01') a ON 
payments.user_id = a.user_id 
GROUP BY payments.user_id) p) t  
GROUP BY diapason WITH ROLLUP) as t1  
ORDER BY total_amount desc;
```

But result I've got is wrong. What should I change to find out sum of paymens for period 2000-01-01   - 2001-01-01. Result must be devided by group due to payments user ever did.

These are tables activity and payments.

```
activity
user_id   login_time
1         2000-01-01
2         2000-03-01
....

payments
user_id     payment_time    amount
1          2000-05-04        10
1          2000-03-01        20
2          2000-04-05        5
...
```

Generally, groups formed by total amount each user ever payed. For example if he payed 50 $ - he is in group "0-100". If he payed 500 - he is in the group "100..." But now I need to know sum of payments users made in each group.

Thanks if you'll try to help!

Comment: So much wrong with this query. What is the "group" you are talking about?

Comment: @sskoko, I am talking about groups formed by total amount each user ever payed. For example if he payed 50 $ - he is in group "0-100". If he payed 500 - he is in the group "100..."

But now I need to know sum of payments users made in each group .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need one of `SUM` or `AVG`:

```
SELECT user_id,
       SUM(Amount) `sum`,
       AVG(Amount) `avg`
FROM payments 
WHERE payment_time BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2001-01-01'
GROUP BY ser_id
```

or this (sum of `Amount` between 2000-01-01 and 2001-01-01 divided by total amount of records for particular user):

```
SELECT user_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_time BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2001-01-01' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) `customAvg`
FROM payments 
WHERE payment_time BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2001-01-01'
GROUP BY ser_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, no need for all those sub-queries.
Simple `sum` and `group by` should do it:

```
SELECT t1.user_id, sum(t2.amount) as total, IF(sum(t2.amount)<=100, '0-100',  '100...') as grp 
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
WHERE t2.payment_time between '2000-01-01' and '2001-01-01'
GROUP BY t1.user_id
```